# how can i change my background_image in a div in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do a meteo application and i want to change my background with my city.

my problem is i can change with the classic cssfile like:

```
body {
  font-family: 'montseratt', sans-serif;
  background-color:white;
  background-image: url('./assets/paris.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat;

}
```

but when i retire it and i try in a div like this it doesn't function:

```
    <div style={{background_image: 'url(./assets/paris.jpg)'}}>
```

i don't understand why.

There is my entire code but i don't think it's useful

```
function Accueil()
{

  
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const [time, setTime] = useState(Date.now());
  const [city, setCity] = useState('')
  const [fond, setFond] = useState((''))
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setTime(new Date().toLocaleString()), 1000);
    return () => {
      
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
  
   const sendtemp = (props) => {
    fetch('getmeteo/?city=' + props) 
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      responseData.temp -= 273.15
      responseData.temp = responseData.temp.toFixed(2)
      responseData.temp = responseData.temp + "°C"
      setWeather(responseData);
      const pro = props.toLowerCase()
      setFond("./assets/" + pro + ".jpg")
      const pop = pro.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pro.substring(1)

      setCity(pop)
      setQuery('')
    })
  }
  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter"){
      setQuery('')
      sendtemp(query);

    }
  }

  
  return (
    <div style={{background_image: 'url(./assets/paris.jpg)'}}>

      

<main>
      
        <div className="search-box">
          <input
          type="text"
          className="search-bar"
          placeholder="Search..."
        
          onChange={e =>setQuery(e.target.value)}
          value = {query}
          onKeyPress={search}
          />
          
        </div>
              <div className="location">
              {(time)}
        </div>
        {weather.temp ? (
       <div className="weather-box">
        
       {weather.temp}
         </div>
      ) : ( <div></div>)}
        
        <div className="location">
            {city}
        </div>

        </main>
   
    <div>
      
    </div>
    </div>
    
  
  );
}
```

thanks for your answers

Comment: You need `backgroundImage`, not `background_image`

Comment: it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/xvsy18c9/ (keep in mind that the URL you're passing is a client-side URL, not a react app file system url)

Comment: Here's a React sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-microservice-dqtdw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

** changed response

Looking at the code, there is no reason to have the curly braces, as there is nothing dynamic being rendered. I imagine it should be written the same as a standard HTML element.

```
 <div style="background_image: url(./assets/paris.jpg)">
```

Comment: i already tried it but it gives me: Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. In that case, reference the quotes like this <div style={{ 
      backgroundImage: `url("./assets/paris.jpg")` 
    }}>  ( back ticks around the url, and double quotes inside the content)

Comment: Thanks for yours answers! that was my first idea, but it gives me   Line 50:39:  'url' is not defined  no-undef :

Comment: The main issue here is that the url needs to be a relative URI the browser can load, not a direct reference to a file.